# What does it mean to be "mailing it in"

Tags: idiom-request

What does it mean to be mailing it in? Can you guys give me example phrases so I can get what it means?

Ex: He's just mailing it in at work today.

Answer (score 3):

“Phoning it in” is an expression; I haven’t heard “mailing it in” but I assume it means the same thing. Basically, it means “slacking off” or “putting in the minimum effort he can get away with”. Some more examples are listed here (see definition 3): https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phone_in

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the [definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mail_it_in) of ***mailing it in*** is:

> To deliver a performance without commitment or effort, with lackluster results.

Here are some exemples:

> "Even though I still have an exam in two weeks, I am going to mail it in and get ready for summer!"
>
> "The manager is going to mail it in".